# When should i use calloc over malloc

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is from Beej's guide to C
**"The drawback to using calloc() is that it takes time to clear memory, and in most cases, you don't need it clear since you'll just be writing over it anyway. But if you ever find yourself malloc()ing a block and then setting the memory to zero right after, you can use calloc() to do that in one call."**

so what is a potential scenario when i will want to clear memory to zero.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the function you are passing a buffer to states in its documentation that a buffer must be zero-filled. You may also always zero out the memory for safety; it doesn't actually take that much time unless the buffers are really huge. Memory allocation itself is the potentially expensive part of the operation.

Answer (score 8):

One scenario is where you are allocating an array of integers, (say, as accumulators or counter variables) and you want each element in the array to start at 0.

Answer (score 3):

In some case where you are allocating memory for some structure and some member of that structure are may going to evaluation in **some expression** or in **conditional statement** without initializing that structure in that case it would be harmful or will give you undefined behavior . So overcome form this better you

```
1> malloc that structure and memset it with 0 before using that structure
```

or

```
2> calloc that structure
```

Note: some advance memory management program with malloc also reset memory with 0

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of times when you might want memory zeroed!

Some examples:

- Allocating memory to contain a structure, where you want all the
  members initialised to zero
- Allocating memory for an array of chars which you are later going to write some number of chars into, and then treat as a NULL
  terminated string
- Allocating memory for an array of pointers which you want initialised to NULL

Comment: Your third point is not guaranteed by the standard. The memory is initialized with all bits zero, and that may not correspond to the null pointer constant.

Answer (score 0):

If all allocated memory is zero-filled, the program's behavior is much more reproducible (so the behavior is more likely the same if you re-run your program). This is why I don't use uninitialized malloc zones.

(for similar reasons, when debugging a C or C++ program on Linux, I usually do `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` so that `mmap` behavior is more reproducible).

And if your program does not allocate huge blocks (i.e. dozens of megabytes), the time spent inside malloc is much bigger than the time to zero it.