# Why does the code below keep on leading to a stack overflow error even with the use of a global double pointer variable?

Tags: c

Why do I keep getting a stack overflow error from the code below in C? Any kind of insight would be much appreciated.

This code was created to add a node to the end of a linked list.

Can someone please review this code and tell me the problem with my insertion process. I am a fairly new programmer and would appreciate any insight.

```
struct linked_list
{
    int y;
    int x;

    struct linked_list *next;
};

struct linked_list **node = NULL;

void list_build(int y, int x)
{
    circular_node *list = (struct linked_list *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct linked_list));
    list -> y = y;
    list -> x = x;
    list -> next = NULL;

    if(*node == NULL)
    {
        *node = list;
    }
    else
    {
        circular_node *array = *node;
        while(array->next != NULL)
        {
          array = array -> next;
        }
        array->next = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a pointer `node`, which you initialize to point to `NULL` (i.e. nowhere). That means you can't dereference the pointer (i.e. `*null` is invalid and leads to *undefined behavior*). What is the reason for the variable to be a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: `circular_node *list = (struct linked_list *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct linked_list));` is a problem to review as questionable type.  For better code, use `circular_node *list = calloc(1, sizeof list[0]);` and avoid wrong type sizing.

Comment: Use your debugger, single step through your code.

Comment: Also, I'd [use `malloc()` instead of `calloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8106782/1270789) here.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I am trying to append a node to the end of a linked list, sir.

Comment: You don't need a pointer to a pointer for that. Especially since you don't make the pointer actually point somewhere valid.

Comment: Technically, you haven't provided a [mre] so the above is not running.  `circular_node` is not declared so doesn't even compile.  You don't check return value of calloc.

Comment: @Allan Wind. I am sorry. I will take this into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: A pointer to pointer is only useful when you wish to allocate an array of pointers (not applicable for linked lists) or in case you wish to return a pointer to the caller through one of the parameters of a function.

Comment: @SageKase No need to be sorry.  If you write a better question as outlined in that article, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

@Someprogrammerdude already explained the issue with the `**node`.  A suitable fix would be to use a regular pointer (instead of pointer to pointer).  Here is a working example (also swapped `x` and `y` because it unnecessary confusing otherwise):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct linked_list {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

struct linked_list *node = NULL;

void list_build(int x, int y) {
    struct linked_list *list = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
    if(!list) {
       printf("malloc failed\n");
       return;
    }
    list->x = x;
    list->y = y;
    list->next = NULL;

    if(!node) {
        node = list;
        return;
    }

    struct linked_list *n;
    for(n = node; n->next; n = n->next);
    n->next = list;
}

void list_print() {
    for(struct linked_list *n = node; n; n = n->next) {
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", n->x, n->y);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    list_build(1, 2);
    list_print();
    list_build(3, 4);
    list_print();
}
```

Consider making `node` a local variable and pass it to the two functions.  Or at least make it static to make it file local so you don't accidentally export that generic symbol name.

Comment: If I may ask, why is the condition part of your for loop above just filled with a single variable?

Comment: @SageKase It checks for null pointers. The condition `n` is equivalent to `n != NULL`.